# Rails 3.2 Asset Pipeline and RequireJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, requirejs, asset-pipeline, amd

I'm going to start a rich client-side web application with Ruby on Rails 3.2. I intended to use RequireJS, but it seems to collide with the Asset Pipeline. As far as I know, what the latter basically does is concatenating dependent assets, minifiying and compressing them (correct me if I'm wrong), which does not seem very compatible with loading JavaScript files asychronously.

At a first glance, the Asset Pipeline seems to have much better performance. However, RequireJS lets you organize the JavaScript code in modules easy to reuse and mange its dependencies.

Is there any way to combine both of them? In case there isn't, which one would you choose?

Comment: What is intended to be the usage of RequireJS - in-browser inclusion of js modules or server-side?

Comment: It'd be used in the browser

Comment: It will do the work just fine.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to have a look at this gem https://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails/

Seems to be doing what you want - which is to use requirejs for loading client side while still taking advantage of some of the asset pipeline.

I would be tempted to suggest that I guess that in most cases the asset pipeline would be much faster as it loads a single minified js resource.  The dependency management isn't as good though, so it would very much depend on the app.

Comment: Totally depends on the build process/app. You can use r.js to do the minify into a single file for production, or take advantage of AMD and create packages that load on-demand, or lazy-load packages that will be used later.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to download the RequireJS library and toss it to `vendor/assets/javascripts`. Then in your `application.js` file :

```
//= require require
```

(funny , yes?) , and that should be enough.

This is the easiest way to combine the asset-pipeline and a modular js library . I am not aware of any additional settings this particular library needs , but you can take a look at [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/405-angularjs?autoplay=true) , which describes something similar.

Comment: That's alright, it'll work, but, why not to disable the pipeline then?

Comment: I think if something works fine it should be kept as it is. What would be without the pipeline: uncompressed js back and forth...

Comment: But my point is, the scripts loaded asynchronously would not be compressed, would it? They would not be included in the manifest

Comment: In your case they are loaded on the browser's side. It does not affect asset-pipeline (which compresses js on the server side) . Adding RequireJS (relying on the pipeline) provides capabilities for the browser , not for the server.Summary : added by RequireJS modules are not compressed.

Comment: It seems like Asset Pipeline and RequireJS have conflicting and/or redundant capabilities. The big issue I see is how to serve assets from a CDN where files are fingerprinted and given far-future headers. It would make sense to keep minification and obfuscation and fingerprinting on the server side. One would have to make js/css manifests to create bundled assets server-side that RequireJS could consume.